# Event Monitoring - TheGraph, AWS, Alchemy

Tags: events, aws, monitoring, the-graph

I am looking for any ideas on the best way (from a production standpoint) to have a queryable way to get the balance of accounts in a smart contract which would be deployed on multiple EVM compatible chains (Polygon, Fantom, Avalanche, other L2s). Query volume is expected to be around 1-3 tps. Data can be at most a few minutes old.

Some options I am considering are:

TheGraph subgraphs but can't find much information on their performance/SLAs.

Alchemy notify doesn't look to work in a generic case and is limited to Polygon, eth L2s. Looks like it may work as I can monitor ERC20 transactions to/from the contract.

Custom AWS solution - not quite sure how to listen to event's from multiple chains effectively.

Calling chain endpoints directly - would this break due to getting throttled?

Any input/opinions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Check OpenZeppelin Defender product and look for something called sentinels

Comment: Sentinels may be perfect, looking a little deeper! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Covalent (tons of chains) or Moralis (growing amount of chains) are perfect solutions for you.